# Changing css(transform) in step function in Jquery doesnt work

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

It works for only rotate, or only scale but doesn't work for both.

```
$({rotation: 0, scale: 1}).animate({
            rotation: 360,
            scale: 3
        }, {
            duration: 4000,
            step: function (now, fx) {

                var rot, scl;
                if (fx.prop === 'rotation') {
                    rot = now;
                }
                if (fx.prop === 'scale') {
                    scl = now;
                }
                $('.inner').css('transform', 'scale(' + scl + ') rotate(' + rot + 'deg)');

            }
        });
```

inner is just a h1 tag inside of an outer div element.

Comment: using **[TweenMax](http://greensock.com/gsap)**, it may look like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/8Lxqe3mr/)**.

Comment: TweenMax looks nice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
step: function (now, fx) {

    $('#inner').css('transform', 'scale(' + now + ') rotate(' + now + 'deg)');

}
```

Both `rot = now;` and `scl = now;` use `now` from step function argument.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/thfckdhd/)

Comment: You are using the same variable in the both places, if you console.log(now), you will see that it prints out the second variable, that is scale, which confirms that the div doesn't rotate 360degrees.